# Am I incorrectly mapping an Ajax request to my Controller Class?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, spring-boot

I'm getting a latitude and longitude value from a user on a JSP page and passing it to a Controller class that contains a method that will query a database based on the latitude and longitude and return information on house prices. I want to print this information on a new JSP page, however, I'm running into multiple errors (I'll go into more detail on them). The controller runs the query successfully as I have a print debugger that displays the correct information in Eclipse's console, but the new page JSP page containing the information will not load.

Function that contains AJAX Query on JSP page #1

```
    function parseHousePrice(){

       $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
       var Lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
       console.log(Lat);

       $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
       var Long = marker.getPosition().lng();
       console.log(Long);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/parseHousePrice",
        data: { latitude: Lat, 
                longitude: Long,  
              }, 
       datatype: 'json'
     });

    }
```

Method in Controller class

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/parseHousePrice", method={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public @ResponseBody String parseHousePrice(@RequestBody HousePrice housePriceObject, @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,@RequestParam("longitude") double longitude, Model model) {

    double housePriceAverage = parseHousePrice.ParseHousePrice(latitude, longitude);

    List<Double> housePriceList = parseHousePrice.getList();
    int housePriceListSize = housePriceList.size();

    System.out.println("The average house price for this area is: " + housePriceAverage + " based on " + housePriceListSize + " property prices in this area"); <-- This print statement successfully prints the results fromt he query

    model.addAttribute("houseprice", housePriceAverage);
    model.addAttribute("housepricelistsize", housePriceListSize);

    return "houseprice"; <-- JSP Page I'm trying to pass the information above to
}
```

With the way the controller is set up above I get a `White Label Error` claiming `There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required double parameter 'latitude' is not present` but the print statement still prints the correct query results.

Based on research I saw that an addition of `@ResponseBody` might solve the issue but when I add a `@ResponseBody` to the controller like so

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/parseHousePrice", method={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public @ResponseBody String parseHousePrice(@RequestBody HousePrice housePriceObject, @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,@RequestParam("longitude") double longitude, Model model) {

same code

return "houseprice";
}
```

I get the following error `There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String com.dit.arearatingsystem.web.UserController.parseHousePrice(com.dit.arearatingsystem.model.HousePrice,double,double,org.springframework.ui.Model)`

Comment: you are not passing `HousePrice`

Comment: Would you mind elaborating please?

Comment: `parseHousePrice` method in your controller takes three arguments, latitude, longitude and an object of type HousePrice, you are passing lat and long, but not passing HousingPrice object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RequestBody HousePrice housePriceObject, @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,@RequestParam("longitude") double longitude, Model model`

Means controller expects 3 values from the incoming HTTP request while AJAX is passing just latitude and longitude.

Comment: Hey @gargkshitiz thanks for the reply. I removed the `housePriceObject` as I actually don't think I need it. However I still get the error that `There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required double parameter 'latitude' is not present`. Could there be another reason for this issue?

Comment: Debug parseHousePrice in your browser and see what values it is passing

Comment: Debugging in the browser just shows the latitude and longitude being sent from the ajax query to the controller, and the debug in the controller shows the queried result based on the latitude and longitude.

Comment: If you are seeing the queried result after debug log within controller class, that means request has already come in. So why you would see 400 error in logs? Can you once check your API from any REST client, say Fiddler, instead?